# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: python, json, urllib, coursera-api

Here is the code..

```
address_input = input("Enter location: ")
params = {"sensor": "false", "address": address_input}
serviceurl = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/json?"
url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
print("Retrieving ", url)
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
print('Retrieved', len(data), 'characters')
json_obj = json.loads(data)
place_id = json_obj["results"][0]["place_id"]
print("Place id", place_id)
```

and here is the error that i am getting

[here is the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CKke.png)

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that you have JSONlines as a response, not JSON

Comment: I tried to edit your title and that exact error already exiats as a question. Please research your issue begore asking.

Comment: Have you even thought of printing `data` because that is presumably not json. Pretty basic debugging 101. And please edit yur code to be MCVE https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help potential answerers understand precisely the setup/problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Requires:

- urllib `pip install urllib`
- requests `pip install requests`

## Code

```py
import json
import urllib
import requests

address_input = input("Enter location: ")
params = {"sensor": "false", "address": address_input, "key": 42}

serviceurl = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/json?"
url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)

print("Retrieving ", url)
resp = requests.get(url)
print('Retrieved', len(resp.content), 'characters')

json_obj = json.loads(resp.content)
place_id = json_obj["results"][0]["place_id"]

print("Place id", place_id)
```

## Output

```py
Enter location: UK
Retrieving  http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/json?sensor=false&address=UK&key=42
Retrieved 1196 characters
Place id ChIJqZHHQhE7WgIReiWIMkOg-MQ
```